# Permission Denied when installing openstreetmap server

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, ubuntu, mapnik, nominatim

I am installing a tile server from this [link](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) on my Ubuntu Machine 14.04. The problem I am facing is in this line :

```
./make.py
cd ../OSMBright/
carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml
```

Whenever I enter '`carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml`' it is giving me permission denied error. I have also tried with `sudo carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml` but still it is giving me permission denied. I am stuck here at this stage and I need to install this server. See I have tried all combination to execute this command[image]. Could anyone help with this?

I tried to post this question on Ubuntu forum but they don't have the proper tags that I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you ran into has nothing to do with carto, it's an issue with your shell command, when you run `sudo carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml` carto runs as root, but the file write happens as your normal permission level, to do what your looking for you can `sudo sh -c "carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml"`

Comment: My reputation is too low to give you thumbs up but I have accepted your answer. I resolved it earlier though, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the error by following these steps:

Step 1- Create a new file `OSMBright.xml` in the same folder.

Step 2- Type `'ls -l'` and see the read and write permission of `OSMBright.xml` file.

Step 3- `sudo Chmod 777 OSMBright.xml` and it will change the read/write permission of the file.

Step 4 - Now do `sudo carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml` and output will be saved in `OSMBright.xml` file :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look ath these instructions from a mapbox article:

[osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart/)

There is a section with hints for setting right permissions for database access.

Maybe the issue is hidden there?

Comment: @I resolved it by creating a new file then changed its permission and redirected my output. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Correct. Its the issue with your shell command which can easily be resolved with sudo sh -c "carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml"